# How do I determine, if Observable has never received anything?

Tags: meteor, ionic2, rxjs5

How do I determine, if the Observable is "empty"?
Better, that it has **never** received anything.

My code looks like this:
`spots: Observable<Spot[]>;`

And I've tried several things I found on Google like:

```
spots.isEmpty();
spots.length;
spots.length();
spots().length;
spots.first();
```

But none of them works like I want..
I need this functionality, to fill a list in Ionic2 with `No items found` until the first item is loaded.

Comment: You need to show that in a view? Because if that's the case, you can use *ngIf to check that list and if it's empty you can show the message.

Comment: Yes, I did it like this before, but now my 'list' is inside an Observable and I use a `*ngFor` combined with ` | async` to view it. And as written above, `*ngIf=spots.isEmpty()` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:
I have an variable `let isEmpty=true;` and set it to false when I receive the first Object in the `Observable`:

```
spots.subscribe(() => {
   this.empty = false;
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve it in my code:

```
if ( arrayOfItems  && arrayOfItems.length > 0 ) {
  // display the list
  return arrayOfItems.map((item) => { return item; })
} else {
  // show a message that nothing was found
  return "Nothing to see here...";
}
```

This will check that the variable has some sort of positive value (ie. it is not `null`, `false` or `undefined`) and that the array has at least one value. If that is not the case then display a message that nothing was found.

Comment: This only checks if the array is empty. But I don't have only an array. I have an Observable, and I don't know, how to check it's emptiness in this case.